# can i uninstall a kernel which is now running in a manjaro linux

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, manjaro

How can I uninstall a kernel which is now being used by my laptop.

I have two kernel installed in my manjaro linux laptop

1. 4.16*
2. 4.14*

When I boot into my system 4.16 always runs by default. To run with 4.14 i goto advanced options and then select 4.14. I want to get rid of 4.16 I like 4.14. Can I remove 4.16 while it is running, and do the update-grub. Or if their is alternative way I'll prefer that alternative way
linux linux-kernel kernel boot archlinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the advanced option of Grub menu you should boot the `4.14` kernel then remove the `4.16` version.

To prevent the kernel from being upgraded , edit your `/etc/pacman.conf` , add the following line:

```
IgnorePkg = linux
```

Then update grub.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent misunderstandings, you should never try to remove a kernel *while* it is running.

You can always check which kernel is running by using the following command in the terminal:

```
mhwd-kernel -li
```

The output may look as follows:

```
4.14.74-1-MANJARO (linux414)
The following kernels are installed in your system:
* linux414
* linux416
```

In the above example, the system is running kernel version 4.14.74-1; 4.16 is available but not being used. In order to get rid of 4.16, the command should be

```
sudo mhwd-kernel -r linux416
```

See [Removing Kernels](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Manjaro_Kernels#Removing_Kernels) in the Manjaro Wiki.

I am running kernel 4.14.74-1 on my own system, and even though the Manjaro Settings Manager tells me that newer kernel versions are available (e.g. 4.16.18_rt12-1, 4.17.19-1 and 4.18.12-1), these don't get installed unless I push the Install button.
I never changed `/etc/pacman.conf` to achieve this, since the part quoted in GAD3R's answer reads (on my system):

```
 # Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
 #IgnorePkg   =
 #IgnoreGroup =
```